# Python code not printing the desired result

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm very new to Python, Just as a way of learning i tasked myself with this problem but no matter what i do the result still comes up to 100000 even when the value is less than the (first condition or second condition) and should print 200000. Please, help.

```
price = 1000000
credit_score = 300
income  = 70000


if credit_score and income:
    credit_score > 700 and income > 80000
    downpayment = price * 0.10
    print(f"Downpayment:  {downpayment}")
elif credit_score or income:
    credit_score < 700 or income < 80000
    downpayment = price * 0.20
    print(f"Downpayment:  {downpayment}")
else: 
    downpayment = price * 0.30
    print(f"Downpayment:  {downpayment}")
```

Comment: What were you hoping `credit_score > 700 and income > 80000` would do? Currently that's an expression whose result is ignored.

Comment: The same applies to `credit_score < 700 or income < 80000`. Use those expressions *in the `if` and `elif` statements*.

Comment: This is not legal Python code

Comment: Change your condition to "if credit_score > 700 and income > 80000: downpayment = price * 0.10".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're putting the conditions that you want to test after the `if` statements, not in them where they belong.

```
if credit_score > 700 and income > 80000:
    downpayment = price * 0.10
    print(f"Downpayment:  {downpayment}")
elif credit_score < 700 or income < 80000:
    downpayment = price * 0.20
    print(f"Downpayment:  {downpayment}")
else: 
    downpayment = price * 0.30
    print(f"Downpayment:  {downpayment}")
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly. can you recommend a good book though that is free.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything to recommend.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
if credit_score and income:
    credit_score > 700 and income > 80000
```

Do

```
if credit_score > 700 and income > 80000:
```

Putting a variable *directly* as the clause in an `if` statement (i.e. `if credit_score`) tries to coerce that variable into a boolean. *Any nonzero number* or *any non-empty string* registers as true, which means your code is always taking the first branch.

Instead, what you should be doing is checking the *condition* `credit_score > 700` and the condition `income > 80000`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're already clear about how it works now. I'll just provide another way of doing this:

```
downpayment = price * 0.10 if (credit_score > 700 and income > 80000) else (price * 0.20 if credit_score < 700 or income < 80000 else price * 0.30) 
print(f"Downpayment:  {downpayment}")
```

Comment: @Raguhul thanks for your input. Just out of curiosity what if i want to set up a between statement for each of the conditions in the elif statement. for example, credit_score between 500 and 699 and income between 70000 and 79999. whats the way around that?

Comment: You can leverage the and's and or's based on the logical operation you intend to perform:            `elif (credit_score > 500) and (credit_score < 699) and (income > 70000) and (income<79999): `

Comment: In Python you can simplify it: `if 500 < credit_score < 699 and 70000 < income < 79999`